# Is matrix positive semi-definite?

Tags: matrices, proof-writing

Is the matrix $A + A^T + A^TA$ a positive semi-definite matrix, for an arbitrary A?

Moreover, how to in general approach for proving or disproving these kinds of matrices to be a positive semi-definite?

Comment: Have you tried any examples?

Comment: No, I was looking for more of a general approach previously. But, after the suggestion from @mathguy I tried that example and understood how it's not a positive semi-definite matrix.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is not, in general - not even for 1 x 1 matrices! (Also simply known as "numbers"). Take the matrix $A$ consisting of one row and one column, with the single value in it equal to $-1$.

The "general approach" for **dis**proving such tentative assertions is to give just one counter-example in each case.